# Python unittest TestCase with inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, unit-testing

Currently I have many similar unittest TestCases. Each TestCase contains both data (input values + expected output values) and logic (call the SUT and compare the actual output with the expected output).

I would like to separate the data from the logic. Thus I want a base class that only contains the logic and a derived class that contains only the data. I came up with this so far:

```
import unittest

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input
    def get_result(self):
        return self.input * 2

class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    def check(self, input, expected_output):
        obj = self.class_under_test(input)
        actual_output = obj.get_result()
        self.assertEqual(actual_output, expected_output)

    def test_get_result(self):
        for value in self.values:
            self.check(value[0], value[1])

class TestMyClass(TestBase):
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, methodName)        
        self.class_under_test = MyClass
        self.values = [(1, 2), (3, 6)]

unittest.main(exit = False)
```

But this fails with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'TestBase' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Two questions:

- Is my 'design' any good?
- What's still needed to get it working?

Comment: Note that it's unusual (in my experience) to use `TestCase.__init__` for anything.  Generally, initialization code goes in `TestCase.setUp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The design is (more or less) fine -- the one "hiccup" is that when unittest looks at *all* TestCase classes and runs the methods that start with "test" on them.  You have a few options at this point.

One approach would be to specify the class under test and values as attributes on the *class*.  Here, if possible, you'll want the values to be immutable...

```
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):

    def check(self, input, expected_output):
        obj = self.class_under_test(input)
        actual_output = obj.get_result()
        self.assertEqual(actual_output, expected_output)

    def check_all(self):
        for value in self.values:
            self.check(value[0], value[1])

class TestMyClass1(TestBase):
    values = ((1, 2), (3, 4))
    class_under_test = MyClass1

    def test_it(self):
        self.check_all()

class TestMyClass2(TestBase):
    values = (('a', 'b'), ('d', 'e'))
    class_under_test = MyClass2

    def test_it(self):
        self.check_all()
```

Answer (score 16):

A little late here but recently came into the need to have unit test inheritence

The most elegant solution that I could find is this:

First - you need a base test class

```
class MyBaseUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    __test__ = False
    def test_someting(self):
        ...

    def test_something_else(self):
        ...
```

then to inherit that class and run tests:

```
class TestA(MyBaseUnitTest):
    __test__ = True

    def test_feature(self):
        pass
    def test_feature2(self):
        pass
```

This is the best, and easiset way to have a single viewset inheritence.

The issue I found with multiple inheritance is that when you try invoke methods like `setUp()` it will not be called on the base test class, so you have to call it in each class you write that extends the base class.

I hope that this will help somebody with this somewhere in the future.

BTW: This was done in python3 - I do not know how it will react in python2

**UPDATE:**

*This is probably better and more pythonic*

```
class MyBaseUnitTest(object):
    def test_someting(self):
        ...

    def test_something_else(self):
        ...

class TestA(MyBaseUnitTest, unittest.TestCase):

    def test_feature(self):
        pass
    def test_feature2(self):
        pass
```

So long as the base test class does not extend "unittest.TestCase", the test runner will not resolve these tests and they will not run in the suite. They will only run where the base class extends them.

Comment: I see a potential problem with the code suggested in the update. Since the mixin `MyBaseUnitTest` doesn't inherit from `unittest.TestCase` one can't call `self.assertEqual` etc. in it.

Comment: @steinar You can call `self.assertEqual` but you don't get the type hints for it. This is because python's dynamic nature gives access to `self.assertEqual` after the child class has inherited `unittest.TestCase`

Answer (score 6):

To make this work as expected, you minimally need to:

- Make sure the **init** method of your subclasses test cases match that of TestCase, i.e. `__init__(self, methodName="runTest")`
- Add a super call in the **init** method of your subclasses e.g. `super(TestMyClass, self).__init__(methodName)`
- Add a self argument to test_get_result, i.e. `def test_get_result(self):`

As for whether it's good design, remember, your tests act in part as documentation for how your code is meant to work.  If you've got all the work hidden away in TestCase instance state, what it does will not be as obvious.  You might be better off, say, writing a mixin class that has custom assertions that take inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Could you give an example of a better design with the mixin?

Comment: This answer helped me solve a similar inheritance problem encountered with TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule().  Adding the modified __init__() did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

You are hitting `test_get_result()` twice.  I do not think any `test*()` methods should be in `TestBase` at all.  Rather, use `TestBase` to provide custom assertions, error formatters, test-data generators, etc. and keep the actual tests in `TestMyClass`.

Answer (score 2):

Python's `unittest.main()` executes all tests from all test classes in the current namespace.

One way to not run tests directly in your base class is to move it to a different module (e.g. move `TestBase` to `testbase.py`):

In the file which calls `unittest.main()`, be sure to not import that class into your namespace (don't use `from testbase import *` or similar):

```
import testbase

class TestMyClass1(testbase.TestBase):
    values = ((1, 2), (3, 4))
    class_under_test = MyClass1
```

Answer (score -1):

Chat GPT gave me the following answer which works like a charm:

```py
class MyBaseUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
       self.some_common_resource


    def test_someting(self):
        ...

    def test_something_else(self):
        ...
```

Then we inherit the base class:

```py
class TestA(MyBaseUnitTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()

    def test_feature(self):
        pass
    def test_feature2(self):
        pass
```